# How can you use custom Ant PropertyExpander from within script

Tags: ant

Sample script:

```
<property name="foo" value="bar" />

<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
    var echoTest = project.createTask("echo");
    echoTest.setMessage("${toString:foo}");
    echoTest.perform();

    echoTest = project.createTask("echo");
    echoTest.setMessage("${foo}");
    echoTest.perform();
 </script>
```

Expected Output:

```
 [echo] bar
 [echo] bar
```

Actual Output:

```
 [echo] ${toString:foo}
 [echo] ${foo}
```

....

So how can I perform the string expansion which Ant does?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
function antResolveProperty(value) {
    var propertyHelper = Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.PropertyHelper.getPropertyHelper(project);
    return String(propertyHelper.replaceProperties(value));
}
```